# Profile MPI (PMPI) and Fortran

Tags: c, fortran, mpi

I am writing sample code for profiling MPI code with PMPI (Profile MPI interface).
While an example in C works well, a Fortran similar simple code is not working.

Here is my C code:

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>


int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
   
   int size;
   int rank;
   char b[100];
   MPI_Status st;
   
   
   MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);
   
   MPI_Pcontrol(2);
   
   MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
   
   if (rank == 0) {
      
      MPI_Send(b, 100, MPI_CHAR, 1, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      
   } else {
      
      MPI_Recv(b, 100, MPI_CHAR, 0, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &st);
      
   }
   
   MPI_Finalize();
   
   return 0;
}
```

And the profiling code capturing calls to MPI_Xxx functions:

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>


static int totalBytes = 0;

int MPI_Init (int *argc, char ***argv) {

   int err = PMPI_Init(argc, argv);

   return err;
}


int MPI_Send(const void* buffer, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype,
             int dest, int tag, MPI_Comm comm) {

   int size;

   printf("Sending ...\n");
   
   int result = PMPI_Send(buffer, count, datatype, dest, tag, comm);

   MPI_Type_size(datatype, &size);
   totalBytes += count*size;
   
   return result;
}

int MPI_Finalize() {
   
   int rank;
   
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
   
   if (rank == 0) {
   
      printf("Total bytes: %d\n", totalBytes);
      
   }
   
   return PMPI_Finalize();
}
```

Compiling commands are:

```
$ mpicc -c example.c 
$ mpicc -c prof.c 
$ mpicc -o example prof.o example.o 
$ mpiexec --hostfile hfile --oversubscribe -np 2 ./example
```

The output, as expected, include the sentences:

```
Sending ...
Total bytes: 100
```

While in fortran, the code is:

```
PROGRAM send_recv_mpi
include 'mpif.h'

integer process_Rank, size_Of_Cluster, ierror, message_Item

call MPI_INIT(ierror)
call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, size_Of_Cluster, ierror)
call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, process_Rank, ierror)

IF(process_Rank == 0) THEN
    message_Item = 42
    call MPI_SEND(message_Item, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierror)
    print *, "Sending message containing: ", message_Item
ELSE IF(process_Rank == 1) THEN
    call MPI_RECV(message_Item, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, ierror)
    print *, "Received message containing: ", message_Item
END IF

call MPI_FINALIZE(ierror)
END PROGRAM
```

and compilation is:

```
$ mpicc -c prof.c 
$ mpif77 -c simple.f90 
$ mpif77 -o simple prof.o simple.o 
$ mpiexec --hostfile hfile --oversubscribe -np 2 ./simple
```

However, the Fortran execution does not show profiling messages. It seems that profiling code is not called.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What mechanism do you think should be happening to enable profiling calls in the Fortran version? You appear not to be calling anything other than "normal" `MPI_INIT` etc.

Comment: I thought that MPI_INIT in Fortran is just an interface to the C MPI implementation of MPI_Init, and I would like to capture the call using profile interface.

Comment: In fact, I rewrite MPI_Init() as mpi_init_() and Fortran invoke it. That is, MPI_INIT invokes mpi_init_ in my platform. Inside mpi_init_ I invoke PMPI_Init(NULL, NULL) and works well, but for more complex functions as mpi_send_ I get problems with invocation of PMPI_Send and parameters. Actually, I have no idea of what to do.

Answer (score 0):

The Fortran program does not directly call any PMPI procedures or your intercepting C-provided functions. Whether the Fortran bindings indirectly call them is implementation dependent: your implementation does not.

As Gilles Gouaillardet comments, some implementations (notably MPICH) do allow the interception as developed in this question. However, for those implementations which do not the following reasoning applies.

Although you have a C-compiled object which is linked in to the executable with the Fortran main program, this does not affect the operation of the Fortran program: the Fortran program does not reference any symbols defined by that C object.

For example, the symbol `MPI_Init` defined by the C source file is not the same thing that the Fortran linker is looking for after the Fortran compiler sees `MPI_INIT`. It'll be looking for `mpi_init_` (or some such: precise details will depend on your system).

To have the Fortran program use the user-defined C object you will need to use proper inter-language operation (for example using standardized C interoperability with Fortran, or manual name mangling). But you'll also need to address more complicated aspects of multi-language use of MPI.

Comment: Fortran bindings are implementation specific. For example in Open MPI, a Fortran binding generally ends up invoking the matching `PMPI` symbol (emphasis on the `P`), which means the wrapper for Fortran has to be written in Fortran (and call the `PMPI` Fortran subroutine). My understanding is MPICH Fortran bindings do call the `MPI` C binding (no `P`), so the OP approach could work with this implementation and its derivatives.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet as long as you get the linking right I don't see why the OP's approach won't work, possibly with a bit of name mangling or F2003 C-interop. But I'm not saying getting the linking right will be straightforward ...

Comment: @IanBush I am not sure I understand what you mean. You can definitely rewrite the Fortran bindings in `C` for the sole purpose of wrapping them. That being said, that looks way too convoluted to me compared to wrapping a Fortran subroutine in Fortran.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, there is the principle of "don't rewrite if you can wrap", but certainly for the simple example of this question Fortran interception makes more sense than going out to C.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Oh I am not saying this is a sensible thing to do. I'm just saying I can't see a reason why it can't be made to work.

Comment: @IanBush I think I see what you mean and that's fair: "has to be written in Fortran" should be taken seriously but not literally :-)

Comment: My objective is to capture the Nasa Parallel Benchmark calls to MPI to obtain the "communication" graph of processes. I started by this simple example to understand how to do it. I am using Open MPI.

Comment: @Toño, if the communication network is what you are after, then you'll probably find that established MPI profiling tools will do that for you out of the box. (There's nothing wrong with trying to understand the mechanisms at a low level, but if you just care about the results then using tools which already exist makes a lot of sense.)

Comment: Thank you very much @francescalus, I will do it. Could you recommend any? Perhaps Tau, scaleP, ...  Sorry, I am a bit out-of-date. My objective is to obtain just a graph of the ranks and their volume of communication.

Comment: @Tono Score-P/Vampir and TAU both should be able to get this information. Profiling Fortran MPI calls got a lot more complicated with the revised Fortran MPI bindings in MPI  3. See chapter 17.1.5 "Interface Specifications, Procedure Names, and the Profiling Interface" (https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report/node412.htm#Node412) in the MPI standard if you want some background information.